# "Manage the summer heat" or "manage with the summer heat"?

Tags: prepositions, verb-usage

Could you tell me if I have to include *with* in the following question?

> How do you manage (**with**) the summer heat, especialy when it's scorching hot days on end?

What I am trying to aks is how the person cope with the heat or how they keep themselves cool. Is the use of the verb *manage* even natural there? If not, could you please provide alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Manage with* (or *cope with)* is better, because you are not talking about 'managing' the heat in the sense of controlling it, as you would central heating!